# Termos usados no CSS

Tags: css, convenções-de-nome

Sabendo que CSS significa literalmente *Folhas de Estilo em Cascata*, regularmente vejo o termo "propriedade" sendo usado para se referenciar a `left`, `width`, `top`, `background` etc.

Diante disso me surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

Essa referenciação está correta? Se sim, então o que são os "estilos" a que se refere o próprio nome "Estilo" na sigla CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Propriedade é somente um dos componentes de um estilo.

CSS pode ser entendido (de uma forma muito simplificada) como uma simples lista de pares propriedades/valores aplicados à um elemento HTML.

Isso fica mais claro se você pensar no style in line. Exemplo:

```
<h1 style="color:blue;text-align:center">Isto é um cabeçalho azul</h1>
```

Note que o atributo `sytle` aplica uma lista de pares propriedade/valor sobre a tag `h1`.

left, width, top, background são propriedades.

Você só pode considerar um estilo quando essas propriedades são aplicadas à um elemento:

```
div {
   left:10px;
   width:100px;
   top:5px;
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Se você ver o significado da palavra estilo, vai ver que um dos significados é : "conjunto de características formais que identificam um objeto.". Então sim, um grupo de propriedades/valores limitados por {} pode ser considerado um estilo